# How can I fix these vkDestroyPipeline* validation errors?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am creating the `VkPipeline` and `VkPipelineLayout` objects like so. I use `shaderc` to compile shaders from string. Both `vk` functions return `VK_SUCCESS`.

```
std::string GLSLShaderVersion("#version 450\n\r");
std::string GLSLMain("void main() {\n\r");
const bool Shader::createGraphicsPipeline() {
 //
 shaderc::Compiler compiler;
 shaderc::CompileOptions compilerOptions;
 std::string vertexstr;
 vertexstr += GLSLShaderVersion;
 // 
 vertexstr += "vec2 positions[3] = vec2[](\n\r";
 vertexstr += " vec2(0.0, -0.5),\n\r";
 vertexstr += " vec2(0.5, 0.5),\n\r";
 vertexstr += " vec2(-0.5, 0.5)\n\r";
 vertexstr += ");\n\r";
 vertexstr += "vec3 colors[3] = vec3[](\n\r";
 vertexstr += " vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),\n\r";
 vertexstr += " vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),\n\r";
 vertexstr += " vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)\n\r";
 vertexstr += ");\n\r";
 vertexstr += "layout(location = 0) out vec3 fragColor;\n\r";
 vertexstr += GLSLMain;
 vertexstr += " gl_Position = vec4(positions[gl_VertexIndex], 0.0, 1.0);\n\r";
 vertexstr += " fragColor = colors[gl_VertexIndex];\n\r";
 vertexstr += "}\n\r";
 printf("Vertex Shader:\n\r\n\r%s\n\r", vertexstr.c_str());
 shaderc::SpvCompilationResult vertexModule = compiler.CompileGlslToSpv(
  (const char*)(vertexstr.c_str()), vertexstr.length(),
  shaderc_vertex_shader, "main", compilerOptions
 );
 if (vertexModule.GetCompilationStatus() != shaderc_compilation_status_success) {
  printf("%s\n\r", vertexModule.GetErrorMessage().c_str());
  return false;
 }
 std::vector<uint32_t> vertexSpv(vertexModule.cbegin(), vertexModule.cend());
 VkShaderModule vertexShaderModule = createShaderModule(vertexSpv);
 //
 std::string fragmentstr;
 fragmentstr += GLSLShaderVersion;
 fragmentstr += "layout(location = 0) in vec3 fragColor;\n\r";
 fragmentstr += "layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;\n\r";
 fragmentstr += GLSLMain;
 fragmentstr += " outColor = vec4(fragColor, 1.0);\n\r";
 fragmentstr += "}\n\r";
 printf("Fragment Shader:\n\r\n\r%s\n\r", fragmentstr.c_str());
 shaderc::SpvCompilationResult fragmentModule = compiler.CompileGlslToSpv(
  (const char*)(fragmentstr.c_str()), fragmentstr.length(),
  shaderc_fragment_shader, "main", compilerOptions
 );
 if (fragmentModule.GetCompilationStatus() != shaderc_compilation_status_success) {
  printf("%s\n\r", fragmentModule.GetErrorMessage().c_str());
  return false;
 }
 std::vector<uint32_t> fragmentSpv(fragmentModule.cbegin(), fragmentModule.cend());
 VkShaderModule fragmentShaderModule = createShaderModule(fragmentSpv);
 // create Graphics Pipeline
 VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo vertexShaderStageInfo{};
 vertexShaderStageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
 vertexShaderStageInfo.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
 vertexShaderStageInfo.module = vertexShaderModule;
 vertexShaderStageInfo.pName = "main";
 VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo fragmentShaderStageInfo{};
 fragmentShaderStageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
 fragmentShaderStageInfo.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
 fragmentShaderStageInfo.module = fragmentShaderModule;
 fragmentShaderStageInfo.pName = "main";
 VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo shaderStages[] = {vertexShaderStageInfo, fragmentShaderStageInfo};
 VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexInputInfo{};
 vertexInputInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
 vertexInputInfo.vertexBindingDescriptionCount = 0;
 vertexInputInfo.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = 0;
 VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssembly{};
 inputAssembly.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
 inputAssembly.topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;
 inputAssembly.primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE;
 VkViewport viewport{};
 viewport.x = 0.0f;
 viewport.y = 0.0f;
 viewport.width = (float) swapChainExtent.width;
 viewport.height = (float) swapChainExtent.height;
 viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
 viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;
 VkRect2D scissor{};
 scissor.offset = {0, 0};
 scissor.extent = swapChainExtent;
 VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportState{};
 viewportState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
 viewportState.viewportCount = 1;
 viewportState.pViewports = &viewport;
 viewportState.scissorCount = 1;
 viewportState.pScissors = &scissor;
 VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizer{};
 rasterizer.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
 rasterizer.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;
 rasterizer.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
 rasterizer.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
 rasterizer.lineWidth = 1.0f;
 rasterizer.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
 rasterizer.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE;
 rasterizer.depthBiasEnable = VK_FALSE;
 VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisampling{};
 multisampling.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
 multisampling.sampleShadingEnable = VK_FALSE;
 multisampling.rasterizationSamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
 VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorBlendAttachment{};
 colorBlendAttachment.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT;
 colorBlendAttachment.blendEnable = VK_FALSE;
 VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlending{};
 colorBlending.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
 colorBlending.logicOpEnable = VK_FALSE;
 colorBlending.logicOp = VK_LOGIC_OP_COPY;
 colorBlending.attachmentCount = 1;
 colorBlending.pAttachments = &colorBlendAttachment;
 colorBlending.blendConstants[0] = 0.0f;
 colorBlending.blendConstants[1] = 0.0f;
 colorBlending.blendConstants[2] = 0.0f;
 colorBlending.blendConstants[3] = 0.0f;
 VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutInfo{};
 pipelineLayoutInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
 pipelineLayoutInfo.setLayoutCount = 0;
 pipelineLayoutInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 0;
 if (vkCreatePipelineLayout(device, &pipelineLayoutInfo, nullptr, &pipelineLayout) != VK_SUCCESS) {
  printf("%s\n\r", "failed to create pipeline layout!");
  return false;
 }
 VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo{};
 pipelineInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
 pipelineInfo.stageCount = 2;
 pipelineInfo.pStages = shaderStages;
 pipelineInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertexInputInfo;
 pipelineInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssembly;
 pipelineInfo.pViewportState = &viewportState;
 pipelineInfo.pRasterizationState = &rasterizer;
 pipelineInfo.pMultisampleState = &multisampling;
 pipelineInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlending;
 pipelineInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;
 pipelineInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
 pipelineInfo.subpass = 0;
 pipelineInfo.basePipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
 if (vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, VK_NULL_HANDLE, 1, &pipelineInfo, nullptr, &graphicsPipeline) != VK_SUCCESS) {
  printf("%s\n\r", "failed to create graphics pipeline!");
  return false;
 }
 vkDestroyShaderModule(device, fragmentShaderModule, nullptr);
 vkDestroyShaderModule(device, vertexShaderModule, nullptr);
 return true;
};
```

However when destroying the objects upon shutdown, I receive validation errors:

```
 vkDestroyPipeline(device, graphicsPipeline, nullptr);
 vkDestroyPipelineLayout(device, pipelineLayout, nullptr);
```

```
Validation Error: [ VUID-vkDestroyPipeline-pipeline-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x7ffff0018220, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_INSTANCE; | MessageID = 0xaeb3d1a6 | Invalid VkPipeline Object 0x120000000012. The Vulkan spec states: If pipeline is not VK_NULL_HANDLE, pipeline must be a valid VkPipeline handle (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyPipeline-pipeline-parameter)
Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-Threading-Info ] Object 0: handle = 0x120000000012, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_PIPELINE; | MessageID = 0x5d6b67e2 | Couldn't find VkPipeline Object 0x120000000012. This should not happen and may indicate a bug in the application.
Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-Threading-Info ] Object 0: handle = 0x120000000012, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_PIPELINE; | MessageID = 0x5d6b67e2 | Couldn't find VkPipeline Object 0x120000000012. This should not happen and may indicate a bug in the application.
Validation Error: [ VUID-vkDestroyPipelineLayout-pipelineLayout-parameter ] Object 0: handle = 0x7ffff0018220, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_INSTANCE; | MessageID = 0x3456cf9c | Invalid VkPipelineLayout Object 0x110000000011. The Vulkan spec states: If pipelineLayout is not VK_NULL_HANDLE, pipelineLayout must be a valid VkPipelineLayout handle (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyPipelineLayout-pipelineLayout-parameter)
Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-Threading-Info ] Object 0: handle = 0x110000000011, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT; | MessageID = 0x5d6b67e2 | Couldn't find VkPipelineLayout Object 0x110000000011. This should not happen and may indicate a bug in the application.
Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-Threading-Info ] Object 0: handle = 0x110000000011, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT; | MessageID = 0x5d6b67e2 | Couldn't find VkPipelineLayout Object 0x110000000011. This should not happen and may indicate a bug in the application.
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: `graphicsPipeline` Where is that? Did its value change while the program was running? Is it a stack variable somewhere?

Comment: It is defined as a member variable `VkPipeline graphicsPipeline;` in the shader class. It's value is the same as when created.

Comment: Somtimes, this happens to me; I wrote a part of code but forgot to call it, so this code just sits there quietly the whole time. Also, why do pipeline layout and pipeline have the same handle ID? I think it could be a good convention to set both of their initial values to `VK_NULL_HANDLE` if you haven't already.

Comment: Managed to solve it, yet thanks for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turned out the destructor to my `Shader` class was being called twice,

once upon window close.

*and* once just after creation - fixing this resolved the issue.